# Does mips branch delay slots propagates through successive branches?

Tags: mips, pipeline, mips32

I was playing around with branch delay slots. Tried that on spim.

```
j some
j a 
j b 
j c 
j d 
ori $9, $0, 13

some:
a:  
b:  
c:  
d:
```

For my surprise it changed the $9 to 13.
So my question is can a delay slot propagate or this is a spim thing and doesn't happen on real mips32 processors?
If this is the expected behavior can someone give me a little enlightenment on what's happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I've never worked with a real MIPS machine, but I imagine that using a branch delay slot for *another* branch will almost certainly cause problems. One common practice on processors like MIPS is to use the branch delay slot for a no-op, such as `ori $0, $0, 0`, just to make sure that nothing executes that isn't supposed to.

Comment: I know that I'm not supposed to do something like that, and I wont do it. I'm just trying to understand more about the delay slot. I mean, I understand that the next instruction after the branch is already ready for execution even if the branch is triggered. But I don't get that a few instruction gets executed. Also is it taking 1 cycle for each branch there?
Something that just came to my mind is that if the rule is: 'for each branch, the next instruction is executed' then it makes perfect sense that it propagates.
Anyway thanks for taking the time to answer it.

Comment: Yes, one cycle per branch is how I would understand it, though it would probably also be perfectly legal for it to unconditionally jump to `some` and ignore the jump to `a` in the first delay slot.

Comment: Will wait for a little bit to see if someone has anything to add to it and will flag it as answered. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

Mips states that placing branch instruction in to a branch delay slot leads to undefined results.